# jpgraph doesn't work

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am developing a web application about statistics, so I am using the library [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net)

What is going wrong is that the graph does not appear. Displays only the browser's broken image icon.

```
$num  = 20;
$num2 = 10;
$data = array($num,$num2);

$graph = new PieGraph(300,200);
$graph->SetShadow();
$graph->title->Set("Utilizadores Registados");

$p1 = new PiePlot($data);
$graph->Add($p1);
$graph->Stroke();
```

I am sure that GD is enable.

Thank you!

Comment: What output you are getting?

Comment: Are you running this from a web server or from the console? What version of PHP, what operating system?

Comment: The output is just an icon. In IE is a red X.
I am running from a web server! PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your output contains PHP error messages, such as:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PieGraph' not found
```

Browsers tend to make it difficult to inspect the source code of a script that generates an image but you should find a way to do it. Commenting out this line:

```
$graph->Stroke();
```

... can be a starting point.

Comment: No... I forgot this: 
include ("../jpgraph-3.0.7/src/jpgraph.php");
include ("../jpgraph-3.0.7/src/jpgraph_pie.php");

Comment: "No" means that you've checked the output and it does not contain error messages?

Comment: "No" means that it does not contain error messages... But I commented the line: "$graph->Stroke();" Nothing happens :/

Comment: "Nothing happens" means that when you go to "View-> Page Source" you see a blank page?