# The "jpgraph" not working, without errors in html

Tags: php, jpgraph

This is my PHP code:

```
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

$data1y=array(47,80,40,116);
$data2y=array(61,30,82,105);
$data3y=array(115,50,70,93);


// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(350,200,'auto');
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

$graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0,30,60,90,120,150), array(15,45,75,105,135));
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

// Create the bar plots
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
$b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
$b3plot = new BarPlot($data3y);

// Create the grouped bar plot
$gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot,$b3plot));
// ...and add it to the graPH
$graph->Add($gbplot);


$b1plot->SetColor("white");
$b1plot->SetFillColor("#cc1111");

$b2plot->SetColor("white");
$b2plot->SetFillColor("#11cccc");

$b3plot->SetColor("white");
$b3plot->SetFillColor("#1111cc");

$graph->title->Set("Bar Plots");

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
```

Reference: [JpGraph Example - Chart](http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_line1.php)

This is my HTML:

[image]

There is no error message on screen. Browser's console is empty as well.

What could be wrong? Do I need to set up something?

I have tried this link: [jpgraph doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069477/jpgraph-doesnt-work) but without success.

Comment: have you tried to check error log ? are you sure about the order of commands ? in docs it says to add new BarPlot and after that setFillColor and when you're done with that, use new GroupBarPlot and Add

Comment: just tried your code, works fine .. maybe you're missing some dependencies ? like `jpg-config.inc.php` ?

Comment: Hi moped. Where are error log? The `jpg-config.inc.php` file is exist at folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have at least minimal "installation" of jpgraph, this is what needs to be (at least) in your `root`:

```
-chart.php
-jpgraph
  -fonts
    -FF_FONT0.gdf
    -FF_FONT0-Bold.gdf
    -FF_FONT1.gdf
    -FF_FONT1-Bold.gdf
    -FF_FONT2.gdf
    -FF_FONT2-Bold.gdf  
  -themes
    -UniversalTheme.class.php
  -gd_image.inc.php
  -imageSmoothArc.php
  -jpg-config.inc.php
  -jpgraph.php
  -jpgraph_bar.php
  -jpgraph_errhandler.inc.php
  -jpgraph_gradient.php
  -jpgraph_legend.inc.php
  -jpgraph_plotband.php
  -jpgraph_rgb.inc.php
  -jpgraph_text.inc.php
  -jpgraph_theme.inc.php
  -jpgraph_ttf.inc.php
```

also be sure to have `GD library` enabled, if you can't access filesystem, turn off `USE_CACHE` in `jpg-config`.

as I wrote in comment, your code works fine with default installation (means I just extracted files listed above, added your code to chart.php in root and I get the image of 3 bars in 4 groups ..

EDIT: additionally, check [troubleshooting tips](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch03s07.html) in their docs and [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530582/jpgraph-cant-include-php-file), which is related to your problem too

Comment: GD has enabled. I need to disable `output_buffering` in `php.ini`?

Comment: yes, additionally you can set `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`, `USE_CACHE` needs to be disabled only if you can't access filesystem, shouldn't be problem here. First disable buffering and enable error displaying. Also doublecheck that there are no characters before `<?php` in your file and also no characters after `?>`. In php, you don't have to include `?>` at the end of the file, so it can save you some headaches like this..

Comment: I has seted `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT, USE_CACHE`. Error message: `JpGraph Error: HTTP headers have already been sent.
Caused by output from file chart.php at line 9.`

Comment: are you sure your file is exactly the same as you posted here? because it works just fine for me, just added `<?php` above your code.

Comment: Yes, `display_errors` and `error_reporting` has setted. `root` is correct. There are other settings?

Comment: Hi, @moped . The code can work, but must remove `HTML` tag. Why?  Only use `include` call php file?

Comment: well yeah .. you must include your chart.php as img in your html page .. (and if this answer helped, please mark as accepted..)

Answer (score 2):

In any case you are using Laravel, you can use this https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/jpgraph (it is not official composer package of jpgraph as they [claim](https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/jpgraph#things-that-jpgraph-ce-is-not) but it is useful, examples are also written in the repo).

When tested, I also got a small grey box instead of a graph.
[image]

But adding `ob_end_clean();` ([refer php.net doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php), *— Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering*) fixed it. And I was able to render the graph.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: ya legend! `ob_end_clean();` does the trick :D, I too was getting that strange gray box